# How do I get the "Microsoft Excel Document" text for a given registered file type?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have an application that displays a detailed list of files stored on the cloud.

In the **File Type** column, rather than just display the file's extension, I'd like to display something like *Firefox HTML Document* or *Notepad++ Document* for files that have registered associations.

How do I query this string from the OS for a given extension in a WinRT application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use app local storage to create a temporary file with an extension and grab the DisplayText [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.displaytype%28v=win.10%29.aspx):

```
static Dictionary<string, string> Extensions = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public async static Task<string> GetDisplayText(string extension)
{
    if (Extensions.ContainsKey(extension)) { return Extensions[extension]; }
    var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("file-test" + extension, 
        Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var displayType = file.DisplayType;
    Extensions[extension] = displayType;
    await file.DeleteAsync();
    return displayType;
}
```

Usage:

```
var name = await GetDisplayText(".xlsx");
```

Returns (on my machine):

```
"Microsoft Excel Worksheet"
```

You might want to cache the extension mapping longer depending how you feel about the performance of this algorithm as it is creating files locally and deleting them. You could use the same file and rename it as well (still disk IO either way). (You'd probably want to add a little bit of exception handling as well).

Comment: Thanks, this is a workable solution. I'm going to hold off on marking it as the correct answer for a few days in case a more direct and efficient solution is offered.

Comment: It's not even simple to do in Win32 programming as there's not an API for it (requires some registry scanning).

Answer (score 1):

Use `StorageFile.DisplayType`.

E.g.

```
var fop = new FileOpenPicker();
fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
var sf = await fop.PickSingleFileAsync();
Debug.WriteLine(sf.DisplayType);
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it requires a file on the local file system, right? I don't actually have a StorageFile instance; I just have the extension string ".jpg"

Comment: @WiredPrairie's auxiliary answer seems to help with that problem.